# How does religion work in Zootopia?

Tags: religion, zootopia

Throughout *Zootopia*, there are quite a few references to religion.

A few examples:

- > Fru Fru: Oh my god, did you see those leopard print jeggings?
- > Nick Wilde: No, it's true. I think I was eight or maybe nine, and all I wanted to do was join the Junior Ranger Scouts. So, my mom scraped together enough money to buy me a brand new uniform because by God I was gonna fit in, even if I was the only predator in the troop, the only fox.
- > Bonnie Hopps: Oh my sweet heaven! Judy, are you a meter maid?
- > Nick Wilde: Who the heck am I to crush his little dreams, huh? Right?
- > Stu Hopps: She's not a real cop! Our prayers have been answered!
- > I thought she was speaking in tongues.
- One of the polar bears does the Sign of the Cross.
- The scouts meet in what seems to be a church.
- The naturalist society had elements of eastern religions.

These indicate that religion exists, though not all may follow one. So who or what do the citizens of this world worship? Are there animal versions of Jesus and other religious figures? Or do they have completely different religions that shares an unspecified number of similarities to Christianity and other real-word faiths?

Comment: [Translation convention?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationConvention)  (Warning!  TV Tropes link!)

Comment: I see no indication that the scout meeting room is in a church.

Comment: I doubt we will ever get a canon answer to this even if they do make a sequel. But if I'm wrong, it'll probably be some variety of [Crystal Dragon Jesus](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrystalDragonJesus).